# A regression test like a glm, but measures the difference in betas

Tags: hypothesis-testing, generalized-linear-model, contrasts

Like the title says, is there a regression test, similar to glm, that says whether a beta coefficient is (statistically) significant based on its difference from the Intercept?

I'm currently doing a glm regression but it seems the beta coefficent p value is based on how much greater the coefficient is compared to 0 (AKA logit 50%). But the data I'm dealing with mostly have odds <50%, sometimes even <25%. So is there a way regression to simply capture the statically significant differences in the beta coefficient?

Comment: A difference must be relative to something.  What do you mean by "difference"?

Comment: By difference, I mean the difference in the coefficients. For instance, my general logistic regression (glm) gives coefficients of B1 and B2; is there a test to measure the difference between the two?

Comment: In all multiple regression models this is called a "contrast."  Please search our site for [GLM contrast](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=glm%20contrast) for answers.